# How to delete some specific files out of a huge list of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, rm

I have a folder with huge number of files.

I want to delete the following files from the folder.

```
ni_mayb17000.mol2  
ni_mayb50000.mol2
ni_fda.mol2
ni_mayb2000.mol2
ni_mayb5000.mol2
ni_in_trials1000_2999.mol2   
ni_in_trials1-999.mol2        
ni_in_trials5000.mol2         
ni_intrials8000.mol2          
ni_intrialsfinal.mol2        
ni_mayb13000.mol2
ni_mayb21000.mol2
ni_mayb45000.mol2
ni_mayb55000.mol2
ni_mayb25000.mol2
ni_mayb60000.mol2
ni_mayb30000.mol2
ni_mayb8000.mol2
ni_mayb35000.mol2
ni_mayb_f.mol2
ni_mayb40000.mol2 
ni_world_not_fda.mol2
```

The files which need to be deleted does not follow a particular pattern, so I was not able to use wild card or pattern. Also if I use patterns, I have risk of deleting unintended files. Since I know the exact file name to be deleted, I was planning to store the required files as a list and then delete it using a `for` loop

```
for i in $list; do
   rm $i -f; 
done
```

How to store this as a list and then do this `for` list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have them in a file, say `filelist.txt`, you could try the following loop

```bsh
while IFS= read -r filename
do
   rm "$filename"
done < filelist.txt
```

Always test, however, before actually erasing the files (e.g. by replacing the `rm "$filename"` with `echo "Would now remove $filename"`).

Answer (score 5):

The issues with using `for i in $list` is described in "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)" and "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)".

Assuming `name.list` contains a manually curated list of filenames referring to files in the current directory, with one filename on each line:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
    rm -f "./$name"
done <name.list
```

This reads each name into the variable `name`, and `rm -f` is called with the variable's value.  If the file does not exist, no error will be outputted (due to the `-f`).  The value in `$name` will have `./` prepended to it before `rm` is called to restrict the effects of the deletion to the current directory.

A  slightly more elaborate variant that produces a bit of output as it goes through the list of filenames:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
    if [ -e "./$name" ]; then
        printf 'Removing "%s"\n' "$name"
        rm -f "./$name"
    else
        printf 'Did not find "%s"\n' "$name"
    fi
done <name.list
```

Or, using `xargs`:

```
xargs -t -I {} rm -f ./{} <name.list
```

This would call `rm -f` with the contents of each line of the file `name.list`. The `-t` option to `xargs` enables "trace mode", which would show each command executed by `xargs`.

Answer (score 2):

If you *know the exact file name(s) to be deleted*, then just remove them directly:

```
rm file1 file2 ...
```

and skip the step of saving them to yet another file and re-reading that file with a shell loop. You then probably want to remove that filename afterwards! Efficiency is in the eye of the beholder, but `rm file1 ...` is one command while other methods are several steps and prone to accidents if you omit quoting or other shell gotchas.